# Change labels along the x-axis of a bar chart with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the labels along the x-axis of a bar chart I've created with pandas.
They have to be the name of the found Items with the lowest calories en before that the name of the category they're in. Like *Category: Itemname*

Datasetsample:

```
,Category,Item,Calories
1,Breakfast,Big Breakfast with Hotcakes and Egg Whites (Regular Biscuit),990
2,Breakfast,Fruit & Maple Oatmeal without Brown Sugar,260
3,Beef & Pork,Big Mac,530
4,Beef & Pork,Quarter Pounder with Cheese,520
5,Beef & Pork,Jalape√±o Double,430
6,Beef & Pork,McRib,500
7,Chicken & Fish,Premium Crispy Chicken Classic Sandwich,510
8,Chicken & Fish,Premium Grilled Chicken Classic Sandwich,350
```

This is my code sofar and it works:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# choose file
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

# read the data
data = pd.read_csv("/content/example1.csv", index_col=2, parse_dates=True)

# Find the Item in every Category with the lowest Calories
LowestCal = data.groupby('Category')['Calories'].idxmin()

LowestCalMeals = data.loc[LowestCal]
LowestCalMeals.plot.bar(x='Category', y='Calories', rot=90)
plt.xlabel('Labels') # tekst onder de x-as
plt.show()

# The found items with the lowest Calories for test purposes
ItemList = LowestCal.tolist()
print(ItemList)
```

With this result

[image]

On the bottom it prints a list of the found items I mean.
This was a test for me if I had the right names found
I have googled a lot for an answer and I think I have to do something with xticks(), but not sure.
Can't get it to work and stuck now. Anyone can help me with it?

Comment: You forgot to provide a [mre] of your dataset.

Comment: Thnx mozway! I've added the example. Was to focused on the correct description :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
ax = LowestCalMeals.plot.bar(x='Category', y='Calories', rot=90)
ax.set_xlabel('Labels')
ax.set_xticklabels(LowestCal.index+': '+LowestCal)
```

Or:

```
(LowestCalMeals.assign(Labels=lambda d: d.index+': '+d['Category'])
 .plot.bar(x='Labels', y='Calories', rot=90)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thnx, this works great. But why is it first printing the labels above the chart? Or is this something of the colab notebook I'm working in?

[Text(0, 0, 'Beef & Pork: Jalape√±o Double'),
 Text(1, 0, 'Breakfast: Fruit & Maple Oatmeal without Brown Sugar'),
 Text(2, 0, 'Chicken & Fish: Premium Grilled Chicken Classic Sandwich')]
<br>
and after that the result you've posted

Comment: It's expected, to remove this add a `;` on the last command: `ax.set_xticklabels(LowestCal.index+': '+LowestCal);`

Comment: Thnx, that's it